# Find the power series representation for $ f(x) = \arctan (e^x) $ and its interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, exponential-function

friends.

As stated on the title, my question is: find the power series representation for $ f(x) = \arctan (e^x) $ and its interval of convergence.

This question got me a bit confused due to the presence of the $ e^x $.

The first path I tried was taking the derivative of the function but I realized that it wouldn't take me anywhere. Then, I decided to do the following:

Let $ g(x) = \arctan (x) $. Then:

$ g'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} $ and so $ g'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot x^{2n} $ for $ -1 < x < 1 $.

Integrating both sides we get:

$ \arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} + C $ and because $ \arctan(0) = 0 $, $ C $ also equals 0.

With that in mind, replacing $ x $ with $ e^x $ we have:

$ \arctan(e^x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \frac{ (e^x)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $

and now for the interval of convergence, using the Ratio Test:

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(e^x)^{2n+3} }{2n+3} \cdot \frac{2n+1}{(e^x)^{2n+1}} \right| = |e^{2x}|  $

and so for the series to converge we must have:

$ -1 < e^{2x} < 1 $

Now, I have two questions:

Can I switch $ x $ with $ e^x $ without any problems?

And if so and assuming my solution and my ratio test are correct, is there any to simplify my interval of convergence?

Really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Pedro.

Comment: You can't just replace $x$ with $e^x$, since the resulting expression isn't a power series. You would have to replace $x$ with the power series for $e^x$, but that gets complicated quickly..

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @Alex Zorn.

You mean that the series would be $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{x^k}{k!} \right)^{2n+1}}{2n+1} $ or that replacement would have to have been made sooner?

Also, if I can't replace, then what does this "true" statement from Wolfram|Alpha mean? [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Carctan%28e%5Ex%29+%3D+%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5B+%28-1%29%5En+*+%5B+%28e%5Ex%29%5E%282n%2B1%29%5D%2F%282n%2B1%29+%5D)

Comment: I mean, if you replace x with e^x you get a valid equality. But it's just not a power series.

Comment: Also, since $e^0 = 1$ what you should really do is find the taylor series of arctan(x) about x = 1...

Comment: @PedroCunha you would want $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{ \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} \right)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Comment: Absolutely, @graydad. Lack of attention on my end; thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Alex Zorn, what do you mean?

Comment: @graydad, why did we have do switch variables? Why couldn't we write $ e^x $ as $ \sum_{n=0} \frac{x^n}{n!} $ ? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just so there's an understanding that the two sums can happen independepently

Comment: Yes, I understand that; my doubt resides in when we have to write a sum inside another sum. Is it due to the fact that we are doing this that we have to change the variable?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and that
$$f'(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}=\frac{1}{2\cosh x}$$
The nearest singularities to zero are $\pm i\pi/2$, so the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f$ around $0$ is $\pi/2$. Now, since $f'$ is even it has a power series expansion of the form $f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{2n}$. Using the fact that $\cosh(x)f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ we see that the coefficients $(a_n)$ can be inductively calculated by the formula:
$$a_0=\frac{1}{2},\qquad a_n=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{a_k}{(2n-2k)!}$$
In particular,
$$
a_0=\frac{1}{2},a_1=-\frac{1}{4},a_2=\frac{5}{48},a_3=-\frac{61}{1440}
$$
and then
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi}{4}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}.$$
That is
$$f(x)=\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^3}{12}+\frac{x^5}{48}-\frac{61 x^7}{10080}+\cdots$$

Comment: Perfect answer. Once the series for $\cosh x$ is available it is an easy matter to find its reciprocal and integrate. But the best part was to use complex analysis to find the radius of convergence. +1